# It is possible to create an array of structs inside an struct?

Tags: c++

I have a struct declared like this:

```
struct folder {
    int dimensionGrup;
    struct groups {
        int factor, power;
    } group;
};
```

My question is: It is possible to create an array of structure "groups" ? Something like:

```
folder *file = new folder[10];
file[1].group = new groups[10];
```

Comment: Did you try to create one? What happened?

Comment: In the code shown, `folder.group` is a single `groups` object. Not an array, not a pointer. Single. (Which makes the name `groups` a bit confusing.)

Comment: The error is at second line at "=" it says "no operator matches these operands", and for the "groups" it says "expected a type specifier".

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
folder *file = new folder[10];
```

will work, but the line

```
file[1].group = new groups[10];
```

will not work, because you cannot assign a pointer to a `struct`.

However, you can define the `struct` the following way instead:

```
struct folder {
    int dimensionGrup;
    struct groups {
        int factor, power;
    } group[10];
};
```

Now, each variable of type `struct folder` contains an array of `struct groups`.

However, I suggest that you rename `struct groups` to `struct group`, and rename the array `group` to `groups`, as that makes more sense:

```
struct folder {
    int dimensionGrup;
    struct group {
        int factor, power;
    } groups[10];
};
```

An alternative would be to define the `struct` the following way instead:

```
struct folder {
    int dimensionGrup;
    struct group {
        int factor, power;
    } *groups;
};
```

Now, `struct` does not actually contain the array `groups`, but rather only a pointer to an array. Therefore, you can now use the lines:

```
folder *file = new folder[10];
file[1].groups = new folder::group[10];
```